# Why does this pointer throw Access violation?

Tags: windows, pointers, pascal

I try to translate a pointer in my code.But it throw Access violation.

I tried many ways on the Internet,but they were all failed.

the main program:

`createthread(nil,0,@make,@cli,0,tmp);//cli is a longint`

and the procedure of make:

```
procedure make(a:pointer);
var
 c:longint;
begin
 c:=PLongint(a)^;
 //here throw Access violation

 ...
end;
```

I expect to get the number in pointer a,how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you need to do to successfully call a C function (like the Win32 `CreateThread()` API) from Pascal.

One of them is set the correct calling sequence: `stdcall`.

Other is get the pointers correct (your original question).

Yet another issue is to make sure the C function declaration is capitalized correctly (e.g. `CreateThread`, not `createthread`.

You haven't shown us your Pascal declaration, nor told us what Pascal compiler you're using.

If you're using Borland Pascal, Delphi or FreePascal, look here for details on calling C from Pascal (and vice versa):

http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/headconv.htm

But if you're using any of those three Pascal's, consider finding an existing Pascal "thread" API, instead of creating your own wrapper.

I hope that helps...

Comment: Your "calling sequence" is generally called "calling convention". More on the subject in this article of mine: [Pitfalls of converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html).